# How to combine array lists gets in python?

Tags: python, django, arrays, list

Hey guys I feel like this is a simple question, but I don't know what these lines of code are called so its difficult for me to search for it :( Hoping you could help me out!

For context I'm getting data from an FQL query in Django and this code is in Views.py. I was wondering if there was any way to combine these three lines or simplify this. Thanks!

```
edu = result[0]['education']
educa = edu[0]['school']
education = educa['name']
```

Comment: `education = result[0]['education'][0]['school']['name']` ?

Comment: ...Did you notice that you have already combined `e = result[0]` and `edu = e['education']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply substitute the references for the variable names in the last expression:

```
education = result[0]['education'][0]['school']['name']
```

Not certain that this is more readable though.

Comment: Thanks guys! Just a quick question what is the proper term for this type of request code? I wanted to get it into one list to make my if statement easier to write. If there's a better way please let me know. Thank you! Also, I'll vote for the answer when it lets me :)

Comment: There is no special lingo for this; we are just chaining the expressions together instead of using intermediary variables. So instead of storing the result of an expression in a variable, then applying a new expression to the variable, we apply the expression directly on the result of the previous expression.

Comment: There really isn't a "proper term" for it because it's really not as special as you seem to think it is. Maybe you can call it "chaining". There is no fundamental conceptual difference between `result[0]` and `result[0]['education']` (which you already do) and `result[0]['education'][0]`. Each array/key access expression returns the thing you access, and then you apply another array/key access to that thing, and so on. You could do this forever.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn is right - I'm not sure about the readability - if you find yourself doing this often enough, then I would be tempted to use a helper function... It makes things clearer.

```
def get_education(edu, main_idx=0, edu_idx=0):
    "Get the name of the school where education was received"
    return edu[main_idx]['education'][edu_idx]['school']['name']
```

Then just use:

```
education = get_education(result)
```

Comment: The function is a good idea, but it's useful to keep it on 3 lines in case it ever throws an exception, so you can see _which_ key/idx it's complaining about

Comment: @gnibbler I completely agree. Just proposed the function so that it's less messy where the info is supposed to be accessed. It's possible using dark magic to trap at which point it failed though... but that's more hassle than it's worth!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it on 3 lines. It's quite readable and really doesn't take longer to run.

You'll thank me when you are trying to track down an `KeyError` or `IndexError` from that block.

Maybe you can improve the variable names. Here's my suggestion

```
education = result[0]['education']
school = education[0]['school']
school_name = school['name']
```